# Tension due to Chords of major scale

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Why the chord iii doesn't have pull towards chord I?
just thinking so because Chord iii contain leading tone in it...
eg in a key of C major...Chord E {E,G,B}

Answer (score 6):

Containing the leading note is a factor.   Containing the 3rd and 5th of the key is another.  That 3rd is a pretty strong anchor.  Strong enough to make us hear iii as an incomplete I(maj7) rather than an incomplete V.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Answer (score 0):

The **ⅶ** tone it contains does act as a leading note, making **ⅲ** in fact quite unstable IMO. However, nothing in the rest of the chord really demands the particular resolution to **Ⅰ**; the chord resolves rather more naturally to **ⅵ** (like **Ⅲ**₇ would, except **ⅲ** is nowhere near as strong), or to **Ⅳ** (perhaps with the third in the bass, which is again the **ⅵ**). Both of those chords also contain the **Ⅰ** note that the **ⅶ** wants to lead to.

Comment: Thanks man...chord iii really wants to go to IV....leading tone resolves there...

Comment: But note that in pop and jazz the maj 7 is a very common addition to the tonic chord, and in that context the 7th has no leading note function whatsoever.

Comment: @LaurencePayne yeah, but Jazz and Pop is nonsense. — ...no, you're right, `Ⅰʲ⁷` can be a perfectly good tonic, but only if it's played in a way so that the major seventh is perceived as the 15th overtone. That doesn't work if the bass doesn't play the `Ⅰ` but the `ⅲ`. (Analogously, the “dominant” seventh can be a great tonic, but only if the minor seventh is played flat enough to be perceived as the 7th overtone.)